# adding users to a group on accepting the app in FB

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

Im creating a facebook application, and I would like to make it like, on accepting the app I wish to add that accepted user to one of the FB group I have, is it possible? or any ways to achieve out of FB? may be redirecting user back to some other page where we may do it via API, please post your ideas if you have any better ways to solve it

Thank you

Comment: No it is not possible. The only thing you can do is to redirect them to the group and they can join if they want to

Comment: @WizKid : Thanks for that, Im really not sure how to do it, Im new to these actually, if you can post me some helpful URLs/apps doing the redirection, that would be much helpful

Comment: You can just redirect them to the group page. They will never get back to your app after that